# How can I use the camera feature with MediaPipe in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mediapipe

I am developing an artificial intelligence application and need to integrate it into a mobile app. I require the use of a MediaPipe camera integration for this mobile app, but I have found limited examples online. While there are many examples in Kotlin, I specifically need to implement it in Flutter. Can you assist me with this